# FATAL: Net::HTTPServerException: remote_file[/var/vcap/services/neo4j/neo4j-hosting-extension.jar]

Tags: cloud-foundry

When executing 'bash < <(curl -s -k -B https://raw.github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/master/dev_setup/bin/vcap_dev_setup)' to install cloudfoundry, I got this error:

```
[Tue, 29 May 2012 10:40:28 +0800] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[Tue, 29 May 2012 10:40:28 +0800] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[Tue, 29 May 2012 10:40:28 +0800] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[Tue, 29 May 2012 10:40:28 +0800] FATAL: Net::HTTPServerException: remote_file[/var/vcap/services/neo4j/neo4j-hosting-extension.jar] (neo4j::default line 22) had an error: Net::HTTPServerException: 403 "Forbidden"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the bug on https://cloudfoundry.atlassian.net/browse/CF-48 and see the workaround on https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/d/topic/vcap-dev/-F0y8QIVhAA/discussion